# How to fetch button element in Angular 2 reactive form for Jasmine/Karma unit testing?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-reactive-forms

I am unable to get button element in Angular reactive form for unit testing. Button doesn't have 'id', so i tried to get below way but i am getting an error like this "Failed: Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': '[(click)="onAppend()"]' is not a valid selector."

This is the way i tried to fetch:

```js
let btn=fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('[(click)="onSend()"]'));
    expect(btn.nativeElement.enabled).toBe(true)
```

This is my button:

```html
              <button class="bx--btn bx--btn--primary" type="button" (click)="onSend()"  [disabled]="!valid || !purchaseForm.valid">Send</button>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you can use `[(click)="onSend()"]` in a css query. Have you tried something like `By.css('button.bx--btn.bx--btn--primary')`? If you don't want to add an id you could also add a class just to identify the button.

Comment: @tomvangreen Tried this i got "Expected undefined to be truthy "